# Shortcode Display WooCommerce Product Variations Dropdown

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode, product-variations

Shortcode Display WooCommerce Product Variations Dropdown

How to display the Product Variations in WooC Commerce with Shortcode???

This is my code:

```
add_shortcode( 'test_shortcode', 'woo_display_variation_dropdown' ); 

function woo_display_variation_dropdown() {

    global $product;
   if( $product->is_type( 'variable' )) {

    $attribute_keys = array_keys( $product->get_attributes() );
    ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $product->get_available_variations() ) ) ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

    <?php if ( empty( $product->get_available_variations() ) && false !== $product->get_available_variations() ) : ?>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $product->get_attributes() as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); ?></label></td>
                        <td class="value">
                            <?php
                                $selected = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ? wc_clean( urldecode( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ] ) ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
                                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array( 'options' => $options, 'attribute' => $attribute_name, 'product' => $product, 'selected' => $selected ) );
                                echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . __( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) : '';
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php endif; ?>


</form>

<?php }

}
```

It does not work as I would like. What I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.